# When a pointer is assigned an address, does the assigning of the address UPDATE the address itself?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h> 
main() 
{   
   int a=0;
   int *b=&a;  
   *b = a + 2;  
   printf("%d", a); 
}
```

**Why am I asking this question? It's been asked 1000 times before, right?**

Not exactly. . . .See, I've checked the questions of this nature asked on this site so far. They answer SOME questions about pointers, but they don't answer the question of what a pointer does to a value that is assigned to it.

**What DOES a pointer do to the value assigned to it?**

So, I have this code in C that has a simple function, then the b pointer is assigned the address of a. The b pointer is updated with the value a+2, oddly enough after this a also updates by 2.

I was under the assumption that pointers were variables like any other, yet assigning a variable seems to change not only the pointer, but the variable assigned TO it as well.

***I'm a rookie and this is not typical to what I have learned so far:***

Why is me being a rookie relevant?

**Well, pointers are VERY hard for new programmers to grasp usually, I believe that this question will bring value to newbies on how pointers work if they do not want to be distracted by google search or cannot pay 50+ dollars for a book.**

***What I THINK the answer is:***

I think that since pointers are different, that in addition to being assigned the variable's value, it also gives the value BACK and updates the value it is being given as well. I do not know why, and I cannot prove why without proper evidence.

Comment: @paulsm4 pointer b points to address a which only holds zero, pointer b is then assigned the value of a + 2, I'm not sure why that updates a itself when nothing specifically was assigned to a.

Comment: @The_Senate `*b = ...` updates the value `b` is pointing to. `b = ...` updates the value of `b`.

Comment: The important thing to note is that `a + 2` is assigned to `*b` (not simply `b`), which is b dereferenced, or in other words, what b is pointing to, which in this case is a.

Comment: Pointer b is never assigned. It is initialized to the address of a, and *its referent* is then assigned the value a + 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` is storing the address of `a`. So when you make changes to `*b`, you're really making changes to `a`.

When you update the value `b` points to (`*b = a + 2`), you update `a` to `a + 2`, which is 2 in this case since `a` was 0 before.

Comment: What would happen if I never assigned &a to *b and just assigned a to *b?

Comment: @The_Senate you didn't assign `&a` to `*b`, you assigned it to `b`. But I know what you mean. What value did you assign to `b` in this hypothetical case?

Comment: a = 9999, so b would just equal 9999 in that case, because I didn't assign the address.

Comment: Can you post the two lines of code here? I'm quite sure what you mean.

Comment: With what you just told me about pointers I'm surprised that nobody uses He who fights monsters as a reference for newbies when it comes to pointers. My professor didn't even explain how pointers worked in this context, and this seems PRETTY important.

Comment: Okay, so if I write a =9999; and *b = a; then I do *b = a + 9999; and then do printf(" a is : %d", a); Since I didn't assign the address a to b, but just the variable a, a will not update, right?

Comment: in that case you'll either write `9999` to a random spot in memory, or cause a segfault, depending on what `b` is pointing to. I can't tell what b is pointing to from your code snippet though.

Comment: If By He Who Fights Monsters you mean the Nietzsche quote, I'm not sure how that's relevant to pointers.

Comment: @The_Senate from your code sample, I can't see what b is pointing to, because you've only shown me `*b = a`. `int *b = ...` is the same as `int *b; b = ...`. I need to see `b = ...` to tell you where b is pointing.

Comment: He who fights monsters runs the risk of becoming a monster himself, once you gaze into the abyss, the abyss gazes back. Think about how you make a = 90; assign *b = &a; but when you do *b = a +2 and print the updated version of a, you get 92 instead. The abyss was the pointer, and a gazed into the abyss and became a pointer itself (not a pointer but the value assigned TO the pointer)

Comment: okay, b = a + 9999; but it doesn't work, the compiler won't take it.

Comment: @The_Senate and what does that tell you?

Comment: That you cannot just declare b once it has been established that it is a pointer.

Comment: What do you mean declare b? you seem to be confused on C terminology. `int *b` is a declaration. `b = a + 9999` is an assignment.

Comment: I'm not confused on any terminology, I know what an assignment and a declaration are. . . .I have just been studying all day and words tend to slip. . . .

Comment: It tells me you can't just assign a + 9999 to b when b has to be typecasted as a pointer, better?

Comment: @The_Senate No worries, I'm tired after studying all day too.

I think what you mean is you cannot assign `a + 9999` to `b` because `b` has been declared as a pointer.

Comment: If b was declared as a simple then it shouldn't matter if I assigned a +9999 to b, what matters is that I'm using b without its proper typecast which was pointer, and since pointers are different from ints, floats, doubles, chars, or other variables, I can't just use b without its pointer.

Comment: @The_Senate what do you mean by "a simple"? Also, what do you mean by "b's pointer"? b _is_ a pointer, it doesn't _have_ a pointer.

Comment: Dude, if b is declared as a double can you just use b again without having double next to it, this isn't the case for pointers, pointers remain next to the variables they are declared next to in order to maintain pointer status, you can't reduce b from pointer status, without *b b is just b, the compiler knows this.

Comment: Pointer to int is a type, just like double. `int *b;` declares b as a variable with type pointer to integer. I can then use `b = ...` to make b point to a different integer, or `*b = ...` to update the value of the integer b is pointing to.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pointers remain next to the variable variables they are declared next to in order to maintain pointer status", or what you think the compiler knows.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of the pointer itself is only have the address of a variable. All the content changes you do to a pointer, the effects will be made in the variable that the pointer is pointing to. If you made instead:

```
b = a + 2;
```

The variable a would still remain with the same content.

Comment: Another example as to why reputation doesn't mean jack. Thank you, Eric.

Comment: If you do this you're going to set `b` to `2`. When you dereference `b` you're probably gonna segfault.

Comment: segfault? I'm not familiar with that concept, elaborate?

Comment: @The_Senate When you try to deference an invalid pointer, you get what's called a segfault. Basically it just crashes your whole program. Try running 
`int main(void) { int *b = NULL; int a = *b; }` for an example of a program that will segfault.

Comment: That sounds painful. Yeesh.

Comment: If you do `b = a + 2;` you'll have an invalid program.

Answer (score 0):

@The_Senate :

1) **int *b=&a;**==>This implies that b is a pointer to integer that has the address of var a

2)  ***b = a + 2;**==> This implies that you are modifying the value of address at b which is a. So by doing this you are actually modifying the  value of a.

Hope this will answer your question.